# How to generate a sitemap.xml from a routes array in Svelte

Tags: javascript, svelte, rollup, xml-sitemap

I am building my routes like this:

```
import Component from "./Component.svelte";
import LangComponent from "./LangComponent.svelte";

const buildRoutes = [
  { name: "/", component: Component },
  {
    name: "hello-world",
    component: LangComponent,
    lang: { de: "hallo-welt" },
  },
];

export default buildRoutes.map(route => ({
  ...route,
  layout: PublicLayout,
}));
```

I want to generate a static *sitemap.xml* in my *public* folder for all the (good) bots in the world to crawl. It should have this format:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
  xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <url>
    <loc>https://www.mycoolsite.com</loc>
        <xhtml:link 
               rel="alternate"
               hreflang="de"
               href="http://www.example.com/deutsch/page.html"/>
    <lastmod>2020-06-04</lastmod>
  </url>
</urlset>
```

So basically I have to add a `<loc>` when there is an element with only a `name` property and additionally a `<xhtml:link` element when the route is also localized.

What is the best way to do this? I have tried so far:

- Writing a bash script which `greps` the routes and generates a new file --> Too complicated with this structure (also way above my `grep` expertise).
- Using a custom `npm` commmand to import the array in a *javascript* file and use the `fs` module --> Ran into problems with babel which seems to not like the imported *svelte* files.

  - Do the same as above, but in an imported *javascript* file in my *App.svelte* to not run into the babel problem. The problem is now that as it does not run in the browser, there is no `fs` I can use.

Is there a way to do this? Can this maybe be done in *rollup*? There seem to be some solutions in *sapper*, but I don't use it.

Comment: I would store the route definition in a separate JSON or YAML file, and import it wherever needed, i.e. in your Svelte project for actual routing, or in a node script to generate the sitemap file(s). The sitemap generation doesn't belong online anyway, it's a script that should be run periodically (as a cron task, for example), with the resulting sitemap(s) published into the public/static directory of your distribution.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that I run into the Babel Problem again, because I have to import the Components which belong to the routes.

Comment: That can easily be solved by storing the component references as string constants in your route definition file (e.g.: component: "LangComponent") and having a table lookup in your Svelte file (`componentLookup = { "LangComponent": LangComponent, ... }`), then use `component: componentLookup[route.component]` in your mapping. A bit tedious but it works. Maybe there is a way to directly de-reference a string constant into the equivalent component?

Comment: Sounds promising and tedious. But it seems like in this case there are no *good* solutions.